Using UHF female cable connectors
I am building an antenna that will have an LMR-240 coax pigtail to feed it. Past antennas I built used SO-239 panel mount connectors at the antenna field point (i.e. no pigtail). For mechanical reasons I can't do that with this antenna. So in place of the SO-239 I want to put a female connector at the end of the coax pigtail, for connecting the antenna to the rest of the coax feedline.
Female UHF connectors are a little difficult to find. I found one where you solder a pin on the center conductor, insert that pin into the connector housing, and then crimp the housing onto the cable (braid) using a ring, much like I do with a male PL-259 connector.
It is not clear to how that pin makes contact with the actual female part of the connector - I think it is just a pressure fit.
My questions...
Do you know how well that pin connection works and whether it is reliable, over time, outdoors?
Do you think it would be better to just put a male PL-259 connector on the pigtail (where the center conductor is soldered directly to the connector pin), and then use a barrel adapter as needed to connect it the rest of the coax feedline?

hm, when asking what a good connector would be and in which place, it'd be good to know which frequency bands you try to work with, and possibly the powers.

The method of soldering a small pin onto the coax, then inserting that pin into a larger pin or socket in the connector, is common in coaxial connectors. It is found on the highest quality connectors, up to many GHz, and it can be a very reliable way of making the tricky centre connection.
As always with connectors you get what you pay for. UHF and BNC have some particularly bad low quality variants. If I had to choose between a \$1.99 front-soldered PL259 and a \$1.99 SO239 with a pin, I think the PL259 would be more reliable. The tiny pin may not make good contact, the fingers inside may not be very springy, it may limit the power handling of the connector. But for a German, Swiss or US-made connector there is no difference in reliability or performance.
Here's an excerpt from the Telegaertner Catalogue - assembly instructions for a UHF Female Bulkhead connector:
First the contact pin is crimped onto the coax inner:

And then the pin is inserted into the connector and the braid ferrule is crimped.

Clamp connectors can capture the centre pin between a stack of teflon washers, but crimps usually have you shove the centre pin in and hope it is captured by some small teeth. This pin-in-pin method allows the actual centre pin or socket of the connector to be permanently secured in the connector body, so the connector can be much stronger than one with a floating pin.
One last thing - if you have any choice, rather use a piece of double-screened PE or Teflon cable like RG223 or RG400 for the pigtail. It's mechanically much stronger and more resistant to bending than the LMR-240, and the extra loss (at UHF connector frequencies) will be neglegible.

Many (all?) BNC(male) to SO-239 conversion connectors have those internal connections that go bad. Some people took an X-ray photo; some others cut it open to figure out what the trouble was. I personally had problems with those, and I'm very skeptical of such things, especially those sold on Amazon.

When you assemble those connectors with an internal contact, do you recommend giving it a tiny drop of Deoxit when assembling?

I also use RG-142 for pigtails and some feedlines in my portable station, and I found it reliable and mechanically strong. Teflon insulators also allow for solid soldering without worrying about the plastic melting.

I've resorted to X-raying connectors. Some professionally assembled $300 BMAs used this pin method as their centre contact has a fancy floating system, but the assembler didn't straighten out the inner before shoving it in, and managed to miss the socket entirely, jamming the pin between the socket and the Teflon. This does appear to be working, for a few months, then and then fails in the field. It was also detectable using a time domain transform. I had to fly around the world replacing cables in products in use... good times. I wouldn't add glue, there should never be tension on the inner.

Deoxit is not a glue, it's a light oil with antioxidants/corrosion remover-inhibitor/contact cleaner blended in.

DeoxIT D5 would be the choice for that brand. However, a better choice would be non-hardening silicone dielectric grease. It keeps water out! I have not any problems with outdoor connectors in many decades of using it.

Thanks for your detailed answer and suggestion on the coax. I expect to go the PL259 route.

For that purpose, I usually use Ox-Gard by Gardner. I usually use it in places that get serviced regularly, like the antenna joints, but I never thought about using it in sealed spaces within connectors. @MikeWaters

Also, for DeoxIT, I usually use D100L with the needle applicator (under magnification) whenever I can access the contact directly. Sometimes, the aerosol spray is the only way to reach, but it also gets on everything else nearby.

@RyujiAB1WX Is Ox-Gard by Gardner-Bender a dark grease? Sounds like something I once used that eventually darkened the material over time.

OxGard is medium gray colored, but I never had a stain issue. Did you use molybdenum grease? It's dark gray. @MikeWaters

No molybdenum disulfide grease for that, no.
